# Using conda envieronment with cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, anaconda, conda

I am trying to use conda through cygwin and what i did do far is:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=/cygdrive/c/users/yoav/anaconda2:$PATH' >> .bashrc
$ source /.bashrc
$ which python
/cygdrive/c/users/yoav/anaconda2/python
$ conda env list
-bash: conda: command not found
```

Then if i do just `python` it goes like that

```
$ python
```

And there are just empty lines and no python functionality but when I type

```
$ pythin -i
$ python -i
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) 
[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> 5+7
12
```

It do fires up anconda python.

Another thing is that if i close the terminal and reopen it it looks like `.basrc` isn't running because:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ source /.bashrc

$ which python
/cygdrive/c/users/yoav/anaconda2/python
```

Would love to hear some suggestions about fixing those issues.

Comment: Usually, `python` goes in the `bin` folder of Anaconda, and this directory gets added to the path `/.../anaconda2/bin`.

Comment: I don't think I have a bin folder there             
`$ cd /cygdrive/c/users/yoav/anaconda2/bin

                            -bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/users/yoav/anaconda2/bin: No such file or directory`
@darthbith

Comment: How did you install Anaconda?

Comment: Just did a fresh instal of anconda 5.0.0 from [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) (for windows 64bit) and nothing changed. @darthbith

Comment: Do you have a `conda.exe` or something like that in the folder? Sorry, I forgot you're on Windows and there isn't usually a `bin` directory on Windows

Comment: Inside `anconda2` there is the `python.exe` and inside `anconda2\Scripts` there is a `conda.exe` file. @darthbith

Comment: Then I guess you also need to add the `anaconda2\Scripts` folder to your path